# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CredisException' with message 'Lost connection to Redis server

Tags: php, apache, magento, redis, fatal-error

Since a few days i get very often the following error

```
apache2: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CredisException' with message 'Lost connection to Redis server.' in /pathtomagento/lib/Credis/Client.php:693#012Stack trace:#012#0 /pathtomagento/lib/Credis/Client.php(538): Credis_Client->read_reply('select')#012#1 /pathtomagento/lib/Credis/Client.php(440): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)#012#2 /pathtomagento/app/code/community/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(135): Credis_Client->select(0)#012#3 /pathtomagento/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)#012#4 /pathtomagento/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)#012#5 /pathtomagento/app/code/local/NBSSystem/Nitrogento/Model/Core/Cache.php(28): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, tr in /pathtomagento/lib/Credis/Client.php on line 693
```

This error will make my server crash, because all clients from apache are being used.

This is on Magento 1.8.1 CE.
Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15, redis-cli 2.2.12

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to suggest anything, but look at this issue on github of this extension:
https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/1

There's some configurations you have to do to work magento and redis.

Comment: Thank you. I posted the question there too. If i get an answer i will post it here too.